# Why can it still compile/run after changing locations of different parameters with different types?

Tags: c++, huffman-code

Last night I spent 1 hour to debug. I was writing a program of Huffman_coding. Part of my *wrong* code is blow:

```
class HTree
{
public:
    HTree* left;
    HTree* right;
    int weight;
    char ch;

    HTree(){left = right = NULL; ch = '\0'; weight = 0;}
    HTree(HTree* l, HTree* r, char c, int w){left = l; right = r; ch = c; weight = w;}
    ~HTree(){delete left; delete right;}
    bool ISleaf(){return !left && !right;}
};
```

And this is one piece of code in `HTree* BuildTree(int* frequency)`:

```
QTree.push(new HTree(NULL, NULL, frequency[i], (char)i));
```

As can be see, the order of these two parameters is inverse - `char c, int w` and `frequency[i], (char)i`. I didn't realize this little mistake at the beginning. The output is, of course, wrong.

But my question is, why can it still compile? or why can it still run? Because the answer/cout is totally wrong. And according to the different types, I think it cannot compile successfully - `char != int`, am I right?

Can anyone tell me why does this happen? Does it automatically converse the `int` to `char` and `char` to `int`, and then it can compile and run, and got a wrong answer?

Well, let me specify more clearly, my **main** question is not whether it can automatically converse or not, it's *why my answer is wrong* if the converse can automatically happen.

The wrong output:

### [image]

The right output:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've already got two good answers. One additional thought though... a `char` is an `int` whose range is (usually) much smaller. You might already know that a `short` is also an `int` with (usually) a smaller range; same sort of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are implicit conversions from `char` to `int` and from `int` to `char`.

Comment: Why is my answer still wrong then, if the converse can automatically happen? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Why is my answer still wrong?". Unless by coincidence `frequency[i] == (char)i`, passing them in the wrong order will result in the wrong values being stored in `ch` and `weight`. In `ch`, which should contain the value of `(char)i`, instead you have `(char)frequency[i]`. And in `weight`, which should contain the value of `frequency[i]`, instead you have `(int)(char)i`. So the code is wrong.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor English expression. I have edited my question, adding two parts of outputs - one is right output one is wrong. @ul90

Answer (score 2):

C++ can convert chars (that are 8 bit integers) to int using implicit casting, if the target type is wider than the source type, which is the case here (int is usually 16 or 32 bits wide depending on the platform, char is 8 bit).
When assigning an int to a char, the compiler usually prints a warning message (but the assignment will work).

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong because instead of frequency you initialize your every HTree object with some `i` value. And the `c` member is initialized with frequency. So because of casting your code is gonna compile and work, and produce wrong results all the way.